# Default seed for System.Random in Mono on Linux?

Tags: c#, .net, random, mono

My evidence for this is purely anecdotal, but it *seems* as if the default seed for new instances of `System.Random` under Mono (...at least on the linux box sitting atop my xbox...) is painfully slow to update. I know this class isn't exactly crypto-strong or anything, but it does bug me that the behavior of this code is markedly different on Windows.

Any idea what it's being seeded with? Also, what could I use that might work better on Linux/Mono?

Edit: This is an easy problem to solve for a program that stays running as it makes new instances of Random ([Using clock ticks as random number seed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10903613/using-clock-ticks-as-random-number-seed) <-- great code sample here, I know), but this program starts, prints results, and stops.

```
$ roll 2d6
4 (1, 3)
```

It's the very definition of trivial, but it's not working all that well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even on Windows, I think you could potentially run into trouble, depending on how fast your machine is. Creating `Random` instances too quickly is a well-known issue in .NET, and even between processes it could happen.

Some alternatives:

- Use [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) to generate random data for use in your program
- Explicitly seed the `Random` class with `Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode()`
- Run a daemon that stays alive (so you can keep using the same `Random` instance over time), and hands out random numbers to processes that ask for them

I don't know if that first option is available on Mono, but it's been around since the early days of .NET so I'm guessing it is. I think the second option is the easiest and would probably work fine.

Comment: You're right, of course; the Linux seeds just seem to be (even) lower resolution than the Windows ones.

Comment: Maybe. Or it could be that Linux just has lower overhead starting a new process, and so in your testing you're able to run the program more frequently than would be possible on Windows. I don't really know. I'm glad you found the suggestions helpful though! :)

Comment: Please also keep in mind, that doing an exlcusiv lock around the `.Next()`-call saves lives (mine included).

Comment: Neither of those is going to matter when the tests are run one at a time and by hand.